# Why does np.linalg.solve give me an error when trying to solve a 16x16 system of equations?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, runtime-error, linear-algebra

I'm creating an nxn matrix with the largest value being n**n. `np.linalg.solve` works when n < 16, but for n >= 16, it gives an error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'solve1' input 0 from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np

def fib_to(n):
    if n==0: return [0]
    fibs = [0, 1]
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        fibs.append(fibs[-1] + fibs[-2])
    return fibs

def get_nth_matrix(n):
    coeficients = [[i**j for j in range(n, -1, -1)] for i in range(n+1)]
    augment = fib_to(n)
    return coeficients, augment

print(np.linalg.solve(*get_nth_matrix(16)))
```

I also noticed that doing `np.linalg.cond` on the matrix had the same problem. It worked for values up to 15, but gave a division by 0 error when n was 16 or greater

Comment: For *n>15* you got values too big to convert to `np.int32`. If you are using windows it is the default dtype for `np.array`. I don't know the implemenation of `np.linalg.solve`. Might try to default to `object` if a `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long` is encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of lists returned by `get_nth_matrix(16)` contains integers that are too large to fit into numpy integer types. When you use `np.linalg.solve()` this list of lists gets converted into a numpy array, but because of this size issue, it produces an array of python objects. The error occurs since `np.linalg.solve()` can't handle this type of an array. You can replace the last line of `get_nth_matrix()` with

```
return np.array(coeficients, dtype=float), augment
```

to fix this - at least for the values that will not overflow the float type.